# 3D model integration on the web with React 16/17, is it possible?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

For the past few days I've been trying to find a way to integrate 3D models onto my website using Three.js & react-three-fiber with react JS 17 & recently 16. The reason for this is that my website also uses 'framer-motion', which requires react 16.8. From what I understand now this is simply not possible as react-three-fiber doesnt support versions of react above 15. I've also tried to use google's model-viewer , but I can't find any documentation on integrating it with react. Could anyone give me any advice on where to start? Any suggestions for working packages with react 16 or 17 would be much appreciated. I know my question is a tad vague but i'm just looking to be steered in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: If big bundle size is acceptable, two different version of React under the same site is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to do just that but eventually I hosted my models on a gh-pages and used Iframe to display them. If anyone else has any other suggestions of doing this a cleaner way I'd be happy to hear how.

Comment: Update: react-three-fiber is now compatible with react 17!